# Greeting Card Flip-View Animation

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, android, android-custom-view

I'm working on greeting card application and i need card flip-view type of View. i've added images for same.
I've been through multiple flip-view like libraries and i found [android-flipview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbsCQ.png)
more suitable for my requirement.
I've made changes in this library to make it flip from left corner like greeting card. 
i'm adding code and screenshot for same.

But, it doesn't work like what i need.

View_Dual_card.java File,I made Changes Like this:

```
public synchronized void buildTexture(FlipRenderer renderer, GL10 gl) {
        if (screenshot != null) {
            if (texture != null)
                texture.destroy(gl);
            texture = Texture.createTexture(screenshot, renderer, gl);
            recycleScreenshot();

            topCard.setTexture(texture);
            bottomCard.setTexture(texture);

            final float viewHeight = texture.getContentHeight();
            final float viewWidth = texture.getContentWidth();
            final float textureHeight = texture.getHeight();
            final float textureWidth = texture.getWidth();

            if (orientationVertical) {
                topCard.setCardVertices(new float[] { 0f, viewHeight, 0f, // top left
                        0f, viewHeight / 2.0f, 0f, // bottom left
                        viewWidth, viewHeight / 2f, 0f, // bottom right
                        viewWidth, viewHeight, 0f // top right
                });

                topCard.setTextureCoordinates(new float[] { 0f, 0f, 0f,
                        viewHeight / 2f / textureHeight,
                        viewWidth / textureWidth,
                        viewHeight / 2f / textureHeight,
                        viewWidth / textureWidth, 0f });

                bottomCard.setCardVertices(new float[] { 0f, viewHeight / 2f,
                        0f, // top left
                        0f, 0f, 0f, // bottom left
                        viewWidth, 0f, 0f, // bottom right
                        viewWidth, viewHeight / 2f, 0f // top right
                        });

                bottomCard.setTextureCoordinates(new float[] { 0f,
                        viewHeight / 2f / textureHeight, 0f,
                        viewHeight / textureHeight, viewWidth / textureWidth,
                        viewHeight / textureHeight, viewWidth / textureWidth,
                        viewHeight / 2f / textureHeight });
            } else {
                topCard.setCardVertices(new float[] { 0f, viewHeight, 0f, // top left
                        0f, 0f, 0f, // bottom left
                        viewWidth /27f, 0f, 0f, // bottom right
                        viewWidth /27f, viewHeight, 0f // top right
                });

                topCard.setTextureCoordinates(new float[] { 0f, 0f, 0f,
                        viewHeight / textureHeight,
                        viewWidth / 27f / textureWidth,
                        viewHeight / textureHeight,
                        viewWidth / 27f / textureWidth, 0f });

                bottomCard.setCardVertices(new float[] {0f,
                        viewHeight, 0f, // top left
                        0f, 0f, 0f, // bottom left
                        viewWidth, 0f, 0f, // bottom right
                        viewWidth, viewHeight, 0f // top right
                        });

                bottomCard.setTextureCoordinates(new float[] {
                        viewWidth /27f / textureWidth, 0f,
                        viewWidth /27f / textureWidth,
                        viewHeight / textureHeight, viewWidth / textureWidth,
                        viewHeight / textureHeight, viewWidth / textureWidth,
                        0f });
            }

            checkError(gl);
        }
    }
```

What i want:

[image] [image][image]

What i'm getting:

[image] [image] [image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WGnB-hXUFk

Comment: Have you got the result?? Please let me know.. I need to implement same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's better you can use page curl which is simple and open source to use.https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/ Hope this might help you.

Comment: i had tried page curl lib. but it gives same effect which i'm having right now.

Answer (score 0):

This animation is a simple scale and skew animation.

Comment: got some link for these animations and reading abt let u know if it works.

Comment: Those links might help : http://c0deattack.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/flip-animation-1/

http://stackoverflow.com/q/5354183/693752

http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2010/07/skew-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

The image appears to be skewing. Make sure you view area is larger than the original card.

Comment: its not my view its a library. and i need to move page on gesture forward and back.