# Skew/Flip Layout in ViewPager

Tags: android, animation, flip, skew

I have a ViewPager where I override `onPageScrolled` to receive the amount a user has scrolled. I then need to flip a view according to the `positionOffset`received from the scroll method. I want to achieve something like this. Flipping all views beside the selected one.

[image]

In my `PageLayout`'s `onDraw` method I have the following code trying to skew the canvas according to the offset received.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Matrix matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
    camera.save();
    camera.rotateX(skew);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();
    canvas.concat(matrix);
}
```

It looks like this only skewing the from the left:

[image]

How to I achieve the same effect from the right? Would be good if it not only skews it but also changing the height so it gives the illusion of being flipped slightly.

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354183/skewing-a-bitmap-only-in-the-vertical-direction ?

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out by the help of your link. It turns out I needed a different viewing perspective to make it work.

Comment: @nilsi can you provide any working sample of it?

Comment: @Rahil2952 Sure the code can be found here: https://github.com/nilsi/CardCarousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the viewing perspective like this made it work.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Matrix matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
    camera.save();
    camera.rotateX(-skew);
    camera.rotateY(0);
    camera.rotateZ(0);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);

    int centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY); //This is the key to getting the correct viewing perspective
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    camera.restore();
    canvas.concat(matrix);
}
```